# usb port use as communications port

Tags: usb

I am using hyper terminal, AT commands to manipulate the mobile phone. It works using the bluetooth connection and infrared where there is ease of creating and configuring a gsm modem(the phone).

The problem is that I have to implement this using a usb port, only comm ports are detected so there is no way to configure a phone connected to a usb port.

How can i map a usb port such that the computer thinks its a comm port?

*Note:* I am not talking about the hardware solution that is a convertor adpater, i would like a software solution.

using winxp sp2,mobile nokia

Answer (score 0):

The phone *usually* expose a CDC-ACM profile which should be interpreted by the OS as a virtual serial port.

On Linux a generic ACM driver has been implemented so most of the phones work out-of-the-box.

On Windows (as you're using Hyper Terminal I assume you're using Windows) your phone manufacturer should have created a driver for you which adds a serial port when the phone is being connected.

If your phone manufacturer didn't provide this driver you have two options: use this non-free software http://www.thesycon.de/eng/usb_cdcacm.shtml or if you're brave enough you can learn ho to write yourself a small .inf file and use the built-in windows library for that (see this small guide http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837637/en-us) but you need to already know how to write .inf driver files.